# Inheritance creating an object - defining the size and delegating an object

Tags: python, function, class, object, inheritance

I'm trying to solve the task, here's the content:

> Define the `Rectangle` class with the x, y, w, h fields, which sequentially store the position of the upper left corner in the coordinate system on the x and y axes and the width and height of the rectangle.
>
> Define a `Window` class containing a name, a color. Create a `Window1` object. Delegate the position and size of the window to the `Rectangle` object.

My code:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y
       self.w = w
       self.h = h

class Window(Rectangle):
    def __set_name__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __set_color__(self,color):
        self.color = color
```

How can I do this part of the task "Create a Window 1 object. Delegate the position and size of the window to the Rectangle object" - can I ask for a hint on how to do it?

Comment: Please see [How to Ask a Homework Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: One way a subclass can "delegate" to its superclass is by using the built-in [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) function to refer to it. Here that would be by defining an `__init__()` method for the `Window` class that called its superclass' `__init__()` method and passed it the required arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution. If I got your question correct.

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        print(x, y, w, h)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h

class Window(Rectangle):

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h):
        super().__init__(x, y, w, h)

    def __set_name__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __set_color__(self,color):
        self.color = color

w = Window(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Feel free to ask any other question. If you find it confusing.